# Windows file with Everyone=READ gives Access is denied

Tags: java, windows, acl

I have a Java based application which creates a number of files on Windows under C:\ProgramData...  These files need to be readable by all users, guests, and automated scripts/programs not run by a user.  One example file is "ca-trust.crt" which is created when the app runs as a Service (no service user is configured so its running as Local Machine context).

My app explicitly adds an ACL for group Everyone to have READ, READ+EXECUTE.  However, my app gets "Access is denied" when trying to open the file to READ.  The same thing happens if I run Powershell as a regular user and run "type C:\ProgramData...".

See image below for permissions and "type ..." command output.

[image]

If I open PS prompt as Administrator and run "type C:\ProgramData..." for the same file it works fine.

Opening the file with Notepad also fails:
[image]

The test system is Windows 10 Enterprise non-AD joined.

Comment: It looks like you didn't grant Everyone the right to `SYNCHRONIZE` on the file. Confirm this using Sysinternals `accesschk -lv <file path>`. FYI, WinAPI `CreateFile` always requests at least `SYNCHRONIZE | FILE_READ_ATRIBUTES` access. The ACE you add should grant generic rights to ensure these rights are included, e.g. `GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_EXECUTE`.

Comment: Thanks eryksun!  Adding SYNCHRONIZE fixed the problem!  Not obvious but win32 rarely is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding SYNCHRONIZE to the ACL in addition to all the READ_* flags fixed the issue.  Thank you eryksun!

Comment: Use generic rights in allow ACEs, and specific rights in deny ACEs. Every type that supports security has to provide a generic mapping, which maps generic rights to specific rights. For files, the generic rights include the standard rights to synchronize and read file security.